# Safely growing a memory mapped file in C++ application

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, shared-memory, visual-c++-6

I have an ancient C++ application originally built in Visual C++ 6.0, that uses a very complex shared-memory DLL to share data among about 8 EXEs and DLLs that all have a pool of values that could be replaced by one or two dictionaries with Strings for the keys, and records for the values.  The application is multi-threaded and multi-process.  There are three primary executables reading and writing into the shared memory area, and several of the executables have 3 or more threads that read/write or "queue" information into this pooled memory area.   About a few hundred places, Structured Exception Handling (SEH) of the `__try` and `__except` is used to filter exceptions, and to try to handle Access Violations by resizing the shared memory, which are in segments managed by a class called `CGMMF` which means growable memory mapped file.

The most salient details are shown here because I cannot find any cohesive source of documentation on the technique in use, or it's safety and suitability.  Experimentally I have found that this library didn't work very well on a single core system in 1998, it works somewhat on a single-core virtual machine running windows XP, and that it doesn't work at all on modern 2+ ghz multi-core Windows 7 64-bit systems in 2013. I'm trying to repair it or replace it.

```
#define ResAddrSpace(pvAddress, dwSize)  \
   (m_hFileMapRes = CreateFileMapping(HFILE_PAGEFILE, &m_SecAttr,             \
      PAGE_READWRITE| SEC_RESERVE, 0, dwSize, m_szRegionName),                    \
   (m_hFileMapRes == NULL) ? NULL :                                     \
      MapViewOfFileEx(m_hFileMapRes, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, dwSize, 0))


void CGmmf::Create(void)
{
    DWORD dwMaxRgnSize;
    if (Gsinf.dwAllocationGranularity == 0) 
    {
        GetSystemInfo(&Gsinf);
    }
    m_dwFileSizeMax = RoundUp(m_dwFileSizeMax, Gsinf.dwAllocationGranularity);
    m_dwFileGrowInc = RoundUp(m_dwFileGrowInc, Gsinf.dwAllocationGranularity);
    dwMaxRgnSize = m_dwFileSizeMax + m_dwOverrunBuf;
    m_pbFile = (PBYTE)ResAddrSpace(NULL, dwMaxRgnSize);
        Adjust(m_dwFileSizeNow);
}

void CGmmf::Adjust(IN DWORD dwDiskFileNow) 
{
    int nThreadPriority;

    __try 
    {
        //
        // Boost our thread's priority so that another thread is 
        // less likely to use the same address space while 
        //  we're changing it.
        //
        nThreadPriority = GetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread());
        SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

        //
        // Restore the contents with the properly adjusted lengths
        //
        Construct(dwDiskFileNow);
    }
    __finally 
    {       
        //
        // Make sure that we always restore our priority class and thread 
        // priority so that we do not continue to adversely affect other 
        // threads in the system.
        //

        SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), nThreadPriority);
    }
}


void CGmmf::Construct(IN DWORD dwDiskFileNow) 
{
    DWORD dwDiskFileNew = RoundUp(dwDiskFileNow, m_dwFileGrowInc),
          dwStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    PBYTE pbTemp;

    if (dwDiskFileNew > 0) 
    {
        //
        // Grow the MMF by creating a new file-mapping object.
        //
            // use VirtualAlloc() here to commit
        // the requested memory: VirtualAlloc will not fail
        // even if the memory block is already committed:

        pbTemp = (PBYTE)VirtualAlloc(m_pbFile,dwDiskFileNew,MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE);

        if(NULL == pbTemp)
        {
            LogError(GetLastError(), MEM_CREATE_MMF, m_szRegionName);

            // 
            //  File-mapping could not be created, the disk is 
            //  probably full.
            //
            RaiseException(EXCEPTION_GMMF_DISKFULL, 
                           EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE, 
                           0, 
                           NULL);
        }

        // 
        //  Check to see if our region has been corrupted 
        //  by another thread.
        //
        if (pbTemp != m_pbFile)
        {
            RaiseException(EXCEPTION_GMMF_CORRUPTEDRGN, 
                           EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE, 
                           0, 
                           NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

So far my options for replacing it include attempting to replace all the shared memory with `DCOM` (out of process COM) and `COM` (in process COM) as appropriate to the places where the memory mapped files, and to guard against concurrency issues by hand, using synchronization/mutex/criticalsection or other threadsafe constructs as appropriate.

I want to know if there is already some thread-safe memory-dictionary type I could replace all of this with.  Even in the above snippet which is less than 1% of the code of this ancient shared-memory-library-for-visual-C++-6, there are things that make me shudder. For example, raising thread priority as a strategy for avoiding deadlocks, race conditions and general corruption.  Maybe that used to make this code stop crashing quite so much on an 80486 CPU at 33 mhz. *Shudder.*

I have the code building and running in Visual C++ 6.0 and also a branch of it runs in Visual C++ 2008, and I could probably get it going in Visual C++ 2010.  What could I use that would give me dictionary semantics, shared memory across processes, and is stable and reliable?

**Update** By "dictionary" I mean the dictionary datatype as known in Python, which is also called a "key/value store" in some places, and in others (like in the C++ standard library), it's known as `std::map`.   Boost documentation that discusses this is [here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_mapped_files)

Comment: This attempt alone deserves up vote.

Comment: Any reason not to use "real" MapViewOfFile shared memory with a CreateMutex for synchronization?

Comment: How does that help me grow a memory mapped file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should take a look at [Boost Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess.html). You can use it to have `std::map`-like objects in a shared memory and a lot more. Its been years since I used it last time, so cannot go into much details, but the library documentation is good and has tons of examples, it should get you going in 30 minutes.

Comment: Boost interprocess looks good. Although the documentation code samples could be constructed a little better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314726/when-boost-library-interprocess-defines-a-named-mutex-do-those-named-mutexes-w/15315088#15315088

Comment: @WarrenP: Well, it is free and open source, hard to complain. I am sure your contribution would be appreciated :)

Comment: On windows it seemed to use a file instead of CreateMutex, thus it performance was quite poor last time I used this..