# When boost library "interprocess" defines a named_mutex do those named_mutexes work properly between different processes, or only with threads?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-c++-2008, boost-interprocess

I think I must be assuming something from the name `boost::interprocess` that is not true.
The documents repeat that `named_mutex` is global [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_mutex.html).

I am unable to make it work though. Two copies of the same executable should be run at the same time, and I expect that a named mutex in a library named `boost::interprocess` might actually BLOCK sometimes. It doesn't. It also doesn't prevent data file corruption in the code below.

Here's some code from the boost docs:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>


int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   try{
      struct file_remove
      {
         file_remove() { std::remove("file_name"); }
         ~file_remove(){ std::remove("file_name"); }
      } file_remover;
      struct mutex_remove
      {
         mutex_remove() { named_mutex::remove("fstream_named_mutex"); }
         ~mutex_remove(){ named_mutex::remove("fstream_named_mutex"); }
      } remover;

      //Open or create the named mutex
      named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "fstream_named_mutex");

      std::ofstream file("file_name");

      for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){

         //Do some operations...

         //Write to file atomically
         scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(mutex);
         file << "Process name, ";
         file << "This is iteration #" << i;
         file << std::endl;
      }
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
```

Here's what I did to it so I could prove to myself the mutex was doing something:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   try{
       /*
      struct file_remove
      {
         file_remove() { std::remove("file_name"); }
         ~file_remove(){ std::remove("file_name"); }
      } file_remover;
      */

      struct mutex_remove
      {
         mutex_remove() { named_mutex::remove("fstream_named_mutex"); }
         ~mutex_remove(){ named_mutex::remove("fstream_named_mutex"); }
      } remover;

      //Open or create the named mutex
      named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "fstream_named_mutex");

      std::ofstream file("file_name");

      for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){

         //Do some operations...

         //Write to file atomically
         DWORD n1,n2;
         n1 = GetTickCount();
         scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(mutex);
         n2 = GetTickCount();
         std::cout << "took " << (n2-n1) << " msec to acquire mutex";
         int randomtime = rand()%10;
         if (randomtime<1) 
            randomtime = 1;
         Sleep(randomtime*100);
         std::cout << " ... writing...\n";
         if (argc>1)
            file << argv[1];
         else
             file << "SOMETHING";
         file << " This is iteration #" << i;
         file << std::endl;
         file.flush(); // added in case this explains the corruption, it does not.
      }
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      std::cout << "ERROR " << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Console Output:

```
took 0 msec to acquire mutex ... writing...
took 0 msec to acquire mutex ... writing...
took 0 msec to acquire mutex ... writing...
took 0 msec to acquire mutex ... writing...
```

Also, the demo writes to a file, which if you run two copies of the program will be missing some data.

I expect that if I delete `file_name` and run two copies of the program, I should get interleaved writes to `file_name` containing 100 rows from each instance.

(Note, that the  demo code is clearly not using an `ofstream` in append mode, instead it simply rewrites the file each time this program runs, so if we wanted a demo to show two processes writing to a file, I'm aware of that reason why it wouldn't work, but what I did expect is for the above code to be a feasible demonstration of mutual exclusion, which it is not. Also calls to a very handy and aptly named `ofstream::flush()` method could have been included, and weren't.)

*Using Boost 1.53 on Visual C++ 2008*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Boost is a wonderful library, and it code examples interspersed in the documentation may sometimes be broken. At least the one for `boost::interprocess::named_mutex` in the docs is not functional on Windows systems.

*Always deleting a mutex as part of the demo code causes the mutex to not function. *

That should be commented in the demo code at the very least.  It fails to pass the "principle of least amazement", although I wondered why it was there, I thought it must be idiomatic and necessary, it's idiotic and unnecessary, in actual fact. Or if it's necessary it's an example of what Joel Spolsky would call a leaky abstraction. If mutexes are really filesystem points under `C:\ProgramData` in Windows  I sure don't want to know about it, or know that turds get left behind that will break the abstraction if I don't detect that case and clean it up. (Sure smells like posix friendly semantics for mutexes in Boost have caused them to use a posix-style implementation instead of going to Win32 API directly and implementing a simple mutex that has no filesystem turds.)

Here's a working demo:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   try{
       /*
      // UNCOMMENT THIS IF YOU WANT TO MAKE THIS DEMO IMPOSSIBLE TO USE TO DEMO ANYTHING

      struct file_remove
      {
         file_remove() { std::remove("file_name"); }
         ~file_remove(){ std::remove("file_name"); }
      } file_remover;

      // UNCOMMENT THIS IF YOU WANT TO BREAK THIS DEMO HORRIBLY:

      struct mutex_remove
      {
         mutex_remove() { named_mutex::remove("fstream_named_mutex"); }
         ~mutex_remove(){ named_mutex::remove("fstream_named_mutex"); }
      } remover;
      */

      //Open or create the named mutex
      named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "fstream_named_mutex");

      std::ofstream file("file_name", std::ios_base::app );
      int randomtime = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){

         //Do some operations...

         //Write to file atomically
         DWORD n1,n2;
         n1 = GetTickCount();

         {
         scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(mutex);
         n2 = GetTickCount();
         std::cout << "took " << (n2-n1) << " msec to acquire mutex";

         randomtime = rand()%10;
         if (randomtime<1) 
            randomtime = 1;

         std::cout << " ... writing...\n";
         if (argc>1)
            file << argv[1];
         else
             file << "SOMETHING";
         file << "...";
         Sleep(randomtime*100);
         file << " This is iteration #" << i;
         file << std::endl;
         file.flush();
         }
         Sleep(randomtime*100); // let the other guy in.
      }
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      std::cout << "ERROR " << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I would love critques and edits on this answer, so that people will have a working demo of using this named mutex .

To use the demo:
   - Build it and run two copies of it. Pass a parameter in so you can see which instance wrote which lines (`start myexename ABC` and `start myexename DEF` from a command prompt in windows)
   - If it's your second run, delete any stray output named "file_name" if you don't want the second run appended to the first.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea of what this does(if it does anything at all), but from the original sample you were missing a `(void)remover;` before `named_mutex mutex(...`.

Comment: I believe the idea with `remover` is to remove any possible mutex that may remain of a previous execution before creating the new mutex and then remove it at the end, once `remover` goes out of scope. I really have no idea what `(void)remover;` does but maybe it is a way to make the compiler not optimize away `remover`. And the same with `file_remover`.

Comment: Well removing the mutex at each time it starts completely DEFEATS the purpose of Mutexes themselves, and this demo is therefore an Anti-demo of a terrible worst practice, either that or the underpinnings of this on Windows are horrible.

Comment: You are supposed to remove the mutex once before running the demo, not in each demo instance.

Comment: The tendency that new users have is to view a demo  as "this is how you do this".  Since apparently in normal use you don't need to delete these, that shouldn't be in the demo.  In fact, normally Boost cleans up after itself, and that makes me wonder if I can trust this library if I have to "fix" these mutexes sometimes, in a way that actually "breaks" them.

Comment: The docs do make the persistent-in-file system point clear but not that deleting the files destroys mutual exclusion.

Comment: So.... `When boost library “interprocess” defines a named_mutex do those named_mutexes work properly between different processes, or only with threads?` You don't directly answer the question - but fix the code